# Keeping JDBC Connection Pool alive from a pure JAVA program

Tags: java, jdbc, pool

My goal: establishing a JDBC connection pool in Apache that will remain alive/reusable between multiple runs of a pure JAVA program

What I know how to do so far:

1) create a JavaScript app in Netbeans that uses JDBC connection pool based on the data source defined in context.xml. Connection(s) established remain alive between multiple runs of the application, the number of database-side connections do not increase irrespective of how many times I connect/disconnect in the application. This exactly what I'd like to achieve in pure JAVA.

2) create a pure JAVA app in Netbeans that establishes and uses a JDBC connection pool.
Problem: JDBC connection pool is established/destroyed every time I run the application.
The application is planned to be a short-lived program, run frequently, with only a couple of connects/disconnects. Therefore the above creation/destruction of the pool defeats its own purpose.

---

Is it possible to combine the best of the above two to achieve my goal:
somehow make Apache create a JDBC connection pool that survives between numerous runs of my pure JAVA application that would use that pool?

Comment: You want a connection pool that persists across multiple JVM runs? If the connections are just doing a small amount of work, then why have a pool at all instead of just creating and destroying a single connection per run?

Comment: I find quite unusual to run a Java application in Apache. Typically a server side Java app runs in some Java app server, like Tomcat. In that case, your connection pool will live as long as the server is up.

Comment: Yes, it is Apache Tomcat, I should have been more precise.

Comment: The reason for connection pool persisting across multiple JVM runs: for example, this might be a canary query connecting to the database every 30 sec. Establishing new connections that often would tax the database too much, therefore the need for the pool. Any issue with the pool or its connections would signal a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're approaching this the wrong way.

There is no connection pool that can survive a JVM restart, since when quitting the JVM, all of the sockets it had open will be destroyed.

If you want to have a persistent connection pool, you'll need a persistent JVM process running, somewhere.

Tomcat is a perfectly adept long running server that can host a connection pool.

If you have a query that you want to run only occasionally, there are different techniques for doing that within an app deployed within Tomcat. Two ready examples are a Java timer, or using a library such as Quartz.

If you insist on "run once" style of programs, you can always deploy a simple WAR that runs your code, once, on startup (using a ContextListener, or a load-on-startup Servlet's init method), and then have an external process deploy that code as necessary. The connection pool with Tomcat will remain active, and you can just deploy the program over, and over again to run the code.

So, there are different techniques that can be applied here.

Comment: Thanks Will.Yes I do want a persistent connection pool, hosted by Apache Tomcat. That connection pool would be used by independent    JAVA programs running in their own JVMs. I was looking for a solution that would avoid redeploying those JAVA programs on each repeated run, if possible.

Comment: Additional clarification: in this case, the goal is to save resources on the database side, not on the client/App server side. Therefore the number of new database connections should be minimized. The JAVA efficiency and resource usage would be considered a secondary issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have learned that the better way to achieve what I wanted was to develop a Web Service and package my "pure Java" code into a Web Service client.